# Python code autocompletion with Gnome-Builder

Tags: gnome-builder

I created a project with gnome builder using the Gnome Application template, opened the main.py file that is generated by the builder to test intellisense for python code and realized that it doesn't work.
The jedi extension for python is enabled, I also installed the jedi package (apt-get install python3-jedi) but intellisense still doesn't work.
What more can I try?

I am using Builder 3.32.4 and Python 3.7